# How can I loop my function as many times = number entered in number_virtuals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I loop my function as many times = number entered in `number_virtuals`?

Here is my code:

```
import ipaddress
import sys
import re

dataList = []


def CollectData():
 ''' this fuction will be used to collect input from user'''

 number_virtuals = input (" How many virtuals are you requesting? ")
 realSerName = input("Please Enter Virtual Name: ")
 realTCPport   = input("Please Enter Virtual TCP port :")
 serName = input("Please Enter Server name, port and IP(format: oser500522:443:172.17.5.1):")

 # dataCenter = input("Please Enter Data Center: Please")

 dataList.append({"number_virtuals": number_virtuals, "realSerName": realSerName, "realTCPport": realTCPport, "serName": serName})

def printconfig(dataList):

print(dataList)


CollectData()
printconfig(dataList)
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

A for cicle may help, something like:

`for i in range(datalist[0]["number_virtuals"]):
    # code to execute as many times`

Don't forget to declare dataList and the return value!

Comment: Would this be another function?

Answer (score 1):

```
import ipaddress
import sys
import re

dataList=[]


def CollectData():
 ''' this fuction will be used to collect input from user'''

 number_virtuals = input (" How many virtuals are you requesting? ")
 n = 0
 realSerName, realTCPport, serName = [], [], []
 while n < int(number_virtuals):
      realSerName += input("Please Enter Virtual Name: ")
      realTCPport += input("Please Enter Virtual TCP port :")
      serName     += input("Please Enter Server name, port and IP(format: oser500522:443:172.17.5.1):")
      n+=1
 # dataCenter = input("Please Enter Data Center: Please")

 dataList.append({"number_virtuals": number_virtuals, "realSerName": realSerName, "realTCPport": realTCPport, "serName": serName})


def printconfig(dataList):
    print(dataList)


CollectData()
printconfig(dataList)
```

Comment: thank you so much, loop works great!! Collecting the data is not as I really want to collect it :

Answer (score 1):

How many virtuals are you requesting? 1
Please Enter Virtual Name: nifi-prod-pci
Please Enter Virtual TCP port :8081 8082
Please Enter Server name, port and IP(format: oser500522:443:172.17.5.1):oser502687:8081:156.92.161.232 oser50268956.92.161.233:8081 
[{'number_virtuals': '1', 'realSerName': ['n', 'i', 'f', 'i', '-', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'd', '-', 'p', 'c', 'i'], 'realTCPport': ['8', '0', '8', '1', ' ', '8', '0', '8', '2'], 'serName': ['o', 's', 'e', 'r', '5', '0', '2', '6', '8', '7', ':', '8', '0', '8', '1', ':', '1', '5', '6', '.', '9', '2', '.', '1', '6', '1', '.', '2', '3', '2', ' ', '5', '6', '.', '9', '2', '.', '1', '6', '1', '.', '2', '3', '3', ':', '8', '0', '8', '1', ' ']}]

Answer (score 0):

is kind of working now, how ever is collecting data only from one loop. I need to collect all data for each loop:

```
import ipaddress
import sys
import re

dataList=[]


def CollectData():
 ''' this fuction will be used to collect input from user'''

 number_virtuals = input (" How many virtuals are you requesting? ")
 n = 0
 while n < int(number_virtuals):
      realSerName = input('Please Enter Virtual Name: ')
      realTCPport = input("Please Enter Virtual TCP port :")
      serName     = input("Please Enter Server name, port and IP(format: oser500522:443:172.17.5.1):")
      n+=1

 dataList.append({"number_virtuals": number_virtuals, "realSerName": realSerName, "realTCPport": realTCPport, "serName": serName})


def printconfig(dataList):
    print(dataList)


CollectData()
printconfig(dataList)




How many virtuals are you requesting? 2
Please Enter Virtual Name: test-lap
Please Enter Virtual TCP port :443
Please Enter Server name, port and IP(format: oser500522:443:172.17.5.1):osr1234
Please Enter Virtual Name: zenk-233
Please Enter Virtual TCP port :7887898
Please Enter Server name, port and IP(format: oser500522:443:172.17.5.1):kkkkkkkkk
[{'number_virtuals': '2', 'realSerName': 'zenk-233', 'realTCPport': '7887898', 'serName': 'kkkkkkkkk'}]
```